# Qual melhor forma de checar se um objeto está vazio?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
let obj = {};
```

Se tento validar `obj.length` me retorna um `undefined`, então recorri a alternativa do Object.keys.. `Object.keys(obj).length`.. resolveu meu problema.. porém gostaria de saber se existe alguma alternativa para isso? alguma função nativa do javascript.. sei la!

Obrigado!

Comment: Não  sei se  te ajuda, mas no CSS tem "função" nativa para isso, chama `:empty` []´s

Comment: No meu caso é inviável utilizar CSS para essa validação..

Answer (score 6):

Você pode criar uma função que percorrerá as propriedades do objeto e te retornará a resposta.
Caso o for precorra alguma propriedade do objeto, logo ele não é vazio, retornará `false`. Caso ele não percorra o for, retornará `true`
Tem um exemplo de código abaixo:

```js
function objIsEmpty(obj) {
  for (let prop in obj) {return false}
  return true;
}

const obj = {'id': 1};
const obj2 = {};
const obj3 = new Object(); // obj vazio
const obj4 = {};
obj4.id = 2;
obj4.nome = 'Teste';

console.log(objIsEmpty(obj), obj);
console.log(objIsEmpty(obj2), obj2);
console.log(objIsEmpty(obj3), obj3);
console.log(objIsEmpty(obj4), obj4);
```

Veja se isso te atende. Qualquer dúvida, só falar.

Answer (score -3):

Para este caso, pode ser verificado da mesma forma que se verifica um atributo 
null.

```
 if(obj.length == null){
  ...código
 }
```

Ou usando o método: hasOwnProperty('Atributo'), onde retorna um booleando informando se essa propiedade é nula ou não

```
obj = new Object(); 
obj.propUm = null;
obj.hasOwnProperty('propUm'); // retorna true
obj.propDois = undefined;
obj.hasOwnProperty('propDois'); // retorna true
```

Caso queira realmente instanciar um objeto null, deve-se fazer da seguinte forma:

```
obj = null
```

Pois ao criar obj = {}, você está instanciando um objeto (portanto deixando de ser null)

Comment: Brother esse if `if(obj.length == null)` não atende.. pois o objeto mesmo estando vazio ou com attributos, não vai ser igual a `null`

Comment: E hasOwnProperty também não atende, pois não quero checar se existe uma prop.. no obj, e sim se ele está vazio ou não..

Comment: Talvez você não tenha entendido a pergunta! =/